# How can I use the index of this image carousel to return the actual image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I've been trying for a few hours to select the center image (or current image) in my carousel. Once selected, I'd like to display the same image in a center-of-screen view-port; think scrolling through photo previews while the current photo is in a larger display. As you scroll, the center image is dynamically changing so the view port will too.

Here is my HTML where I'm trying to propogate said carousel image; the view port:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:480px;border:1px solid #fff">
     <div id="view-port">
     </div>
</div>
```

The closest I've gotten to something successful is:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var centerSlide = document.createElement("img");
    centerSlide.src = $('#myCarousel').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
    document.getElementById("view-port").appendChild(centerSlide);
    console.log(centerSlide);
};
```

Which logs

```
<img src="0">
```

as expected, the index of the currentSlide. This can be observed here:

https://jsfiddle.net/positivecharge8/nddaj84x/

But I can't figure out how to get the image so I can reference it to put into a div. I understand that the code that I have now won't dynamically change the view port div image as I scroll through the carousel- that's okay, for now I'd like to at least get *some* image up there. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle/jsbin demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Sure! Give me a few minutes, please.

Comment: @NateW I'm having issues with jsfiddle right now; it won't save my new code for linking. When I click the link, it gives me the unsaved draft :/

Comment: @NateW I think this should work!!!
https://jsfiddle.net/positivecharge8/nddaj84x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$('#myCarousel').slick('slickCurrentSlide');` gets you the *index* of the current image not the *src* of the image. Use jQuery's `prop` function to get the src of the image.

The following will find the current slide, and then get its src and use it for the new image's src.

```
var centerSlide = document.createElement("img");
centerSlide.src = $('#shoe-carousel .slick-current img').prop('src');
document.getElementById("view-port").appendChild(centerSlide);
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4g4wbj1g/8/

To make the `centerSlide` update on slide change I would look into using the `afterChange` event. There is some good documentation here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Don't be creeped out, but I love you. I was thrust into this project solo and pretty much had no JS (or jQuery) experience before this, so I've been stuck on this for a day or two now. Thank you so, so much.

Comment: Also, that prop function is damn useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the afterChange event of slick

```
  <div id="slickme">
    <div class="myelement"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png"></div>
    <div class="myelement"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"></div>
  </div>



// On slide change
$('#slickme').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);

  //get the element dom from the page
  console.log($('#slickme .myelement[data-slick-index = ' + currentSlide + ']').html());

});
```

Then you can use whatever selectors you want, if you wanted the img src you could use something like:

```
$('#slickme .myelement[data-slick-index = ' + currentSlide + '] img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me :/


https://jsfiddle.net/positivecharge8/xrsnqqcd/

Comment: if you create the fiddle properly it would: https://jsfiddle.net/xrsnqqcd/1/ You need to include the external resources and setup slick the way you want it to. These forums are for help, not for people to create a working solution for you!